# c# Display the only column from db table and display its contents

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am in the process of making a very very simple .net CMS where the user can login and update a single line of text for their website.

I want to be able to display the **latest** field in column selectionText from my MsSQL Table: homepageSelection and print its contents to my .aspx page.

All the code I have currently:

```
dbAD.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 1 selectionText FROM homepageSelection ORDER BY PostID ASC", dbConnect);
dbAD.Fill(dbRS, "homepageSelection");

if (dbRS.Tables("homepageSelection").Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow selectionText in dbRS.Tables("homepageSelection").Rows)
    {
        Response.Write("homepageSelection("selectionText")");
    }
}
```

`GridView` and `ListView` are great, but there must be a way, only one column and its latest insert content can be printed to the page?

Comment: do you have a column like UpdatedDate ? you can query your source based on this column.

Comment: @Badiparmagi I'm not at the stage yet where I can also save the date in a form, was just looking to display the latest input

Comment: perhaps a label or a textbox control will serve your purpose ?

Comment: @AbdulRehmanSayed Thanks. Would you mind elaborating ever so slightly. Do I need to setup a CodeBehind to display my data?

Comment: it is an aspx page right. you have written it in code behind. what you need is the front...

Answer (score 0):

You may looking for this

```
if(dbRS.Tables("homepageSelection").Rows.Count > 0)
{
  foreach (DataRow selectionText in dbRS.Tables("homepageSelection").Rows)
  {
    Response.Write(selectionText["selectionText"].toString());
  } 
}
```